# Can someone share code for handling Azure oauth2.0 in cypress using javascript and how to add it in the Spec file

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

Can someone share code for handling Azure oauth2.0 in cypress using javascript and how to add it in the Spec file

Can someone share code for handing Azure oauth2.0 in cypress using javascript and how to add it in the Spec file